# The performance of retrieve all columns and multiple columns

Tags: sql

I am learning SQL following "SQL in 10 minutes",

Reference to use wildcards to retrieve all the records, it states that:

> As a rule, you are better off not using the * wildcard unless you really do need every column in the table. Even though use of wildcards may save you the time and effort needed to list the desired columns explicitly, retrieving unnecessary columns usually slows down the performance of your retrieval and your application.

However, It consume less time to retrieve all the records than to retrieve multiple fields:

[image]

As the result indicate, wildcards for 0.02 seconds V.S. 0.1 seconds

I tested several times, wildcards faster than multiple specified columns constantly, even though time consumed varied every times.

Comment: Caching,probably second one reads directly from buffer cache. You should also do the same test but with larger table (250k at least I would say). 9 records is too small to draw conculsions.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: should I follow the book's instruction? @GordonLinoff

Comment: ty, could you please transmit the comment to answer. @LukaszSzozda

Comment: Just testing one case multiple times in some command line interface doesn't mean anything. Just think if you have a table where a row has 1 Kb data on average and its two integer columns (8 bytes + some) is all you need, if you are retrieving 10 000 rows it means almost 10 Mb difference moving down the wire.

Comment: @OnPrinciples There are two already good answer. Feel free to acept any of them.

Comment: It is a funny name "SQL in 10 minutes" :) Author should be expecting readers with 300+ IQ. Names like that stinks.

Comment: It's been 6 hours and you should have pwned SQL by now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kudos to you for attempting to validate advice you get in a book!  A single test neither invalidates the advice nor invalidates the test.  It is worthwhile to dive further.

The advice provided in `SQL In 10 Minutes` is sound advice -- and it explicitly states that the purpose related to performance.  (Another consideration is that that it makes the code unstable when the database changes.)  As a note:  I regularly use `select t.*` for ad-hoc queries.

Why are the results different?  There can be multiple reasons for this:

- Databases do not have deterministic performance, so other considerations -- such as other processes running on the machine or resource contention -- can affect the performance.
- As mentioned in a comment, caching can be the reason.  Specifically, running the first query may require loading the data from disk, and it is already in memory for the first.
- Another form of caching is for the execution plan, so perhaps the first execution plan is cached but not the second.
- You don't mention the database, but perhaps your database has a really, really slow compiler and compiling the first takes longer than the second.

Fundamentally, the advice is sound from a common-sense perspective.  Moving less data around should be more efficient.  That is really what the advice is saying.

In any case, the difference between 10 milliseconds and 2 milliseconds is very short.  I would not generalize this performance to larger data and say that the second is 5 times faster than the first *in general*.  For whatever reason, it is 8 milliseconds shorter on a very small data set, one so small that performance would not be a consideration anyway.

Comment: I would add that with a sample data as small as 9 rows in the MySQL example, the pre-execution time (parsing, preparing, etc.) may become significant, compared to the execution phase time. The difference will be easier to spot with heavy extra columns (BLOBs).

Answer (score 3):

For manual testing the data that's in a table or tables?

Then it doesn't matter much whether you used a `*` or the column names.

Sure, if the table has like 100 columns and you only are interested in a few?   Then explicitly adding the columnnames will give you a less convulted result.
Plus, you can choose the order they appear in the result.

And using a `*` in a sub-query would drag all the fields into the resultset.
While if you only selected the columns you need could improve performance.
For manual testing, that normally doesn't matter much.
Whether a test SQL runs 1 seconds or 2 seconds, if it's a test or an ad-hoc query then it wouldn't bother you.

What the suggestion is more intended for, is about coding SQL's that are to be used in a production environment.

When using `*` in a SQL, that means that when something changes in the tables that are used in the query, that it can affect the output of that query.
Possibly leading to errors.  Your boss would frown upon that!

For example, a SQL with a `select * from tableA union select * from tableB` that you coded a year ago suddenly starts crashing because a column was added to tableB.  Ouch.

But by explicitly putting the column names, adding a column to 1 of the tables wouldn't make any difference to that SQL.

In other words.
In production, stability and performance matter much more than golf-coding.

Another thing to keep in mind is the effect of [caching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/buffering-caching.html).
Some databases can temporarly store metadata or even data in memory.
Which can speed up the retrieval of a query that gets the same results of a query that just run before it.

So try running the following SQL's.
Which are in a different order than in the question.
And check if there's still a speed difference.

```
select * from products;
select prod_id, prod_name, prod_price from products;
```